# Submit Parameters and JSON data in HTTP POST request. Best Approach?

Tags: json, http, post, parameters, request

I want to use the same http POST Web Service to perform similar related functions on the same entity:like add,append etc.

I intended to pass Parameters with **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** to identify the method and the arguments as JSON like : 
`method=func1&JSON={"param1":val1,"param2":val2}`

is this the correct approach or are there other better ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you want to send post parameters to a web service ? And the parameters are in json format?

Comment: Yes, what i want to do is this: 1. Use the same web service for different , but related functions ( Firstly, Is this approach recommended or should we have different web services for different functions ?) 2. Considering Point 1 , is recommended , what is the Best practice to achieve Point 1 ? one way to do it is pass params to POST request in FORM data , where the first param is the method name and the next param is the function arguments in JSON format